# Rename NIC in opensuse

Tags: opensuse, nic

I'm using opensuse 13.1, and I need to rename my NIC from 'em1' to 'eth0'. While I've found several other people trying to rename NICs, I haven't found anyone who seems to be doing it in Suse 13.1. One of the frequently mentioned fixes is changing parameters in the 
70-persistent-net.rules file, but mine is empty. I also haven't been able to find anything in Yast that has NIC names, but that doesn't mean it isn't there.

If it helps, here's an example of someone doing in Red Hat what I'm trying to do:

http://www.sysarchitects.com/em1_to_eth0.

The problem here is that the pathways he references don't always match up with mine (for example, I don't have /etc/grub.conf, nor do I know if I have an equivalent and if I do where to find it), so I haven't been able to use this example to get mine working.

Thanks for the assistance!

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. You're looking for a different [se] site such as [su] or one of the *nix sites.

Answer (score 1):

openSuSE 13.1 uses `grub2`. You will not have an `/etc/grub.conf`. The change in network interface names is a result of running `systemd/udev >= 197`. You are in luck, you can change the device name. Look at the **freedesktop.org** page list below (the folks that brought you `systemd/udev`)

You basically have four options. The four options are detailed here [**Predictable Network Interface Names (I don't like this, how do I disable this?)**](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/PredictableNetworkInterfaceNames/) It is toward the bottom of the page.